# Viewing Linux Library / Executable version info

Tags: libraries, executable

In Windows, EXE and DLL have version info, including at least the following fields:

1. file version
2. product version
3. internal name
4. product name
5. copyright

In Linux Library / Executable:

- Which fields are present?
- How to view such info?
- What tools/libraries to read?

Comment: i have updated some more things please check now..

Comment: ldconfig need root? What about to check a specific libxxx.so file and don't want to execute an exe with --version (it may fail)

Comment: no need root, since /sbin/ path is not set in normal user Environment, you can execute that useing absolute path eg. `/sbin/ldconfig -p`

Answer (score 64):

The version info in not explicitly stored in [an ELF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). What you have in there is the name of the library, the `soname`, which includes the major version.
The full version is usually stored as a part of the library file name.

If you have library, say `libtest.so`, then you usually have:

- `libtest.so.1.0.1` - The library file itself, containing the full version
- `libtest.so.1` - Symlink to `libtest.so.1.0.1`, having the same name as `soname`
- `libtest.so` - Symlink to `libtest.so.1` used for linking.

In the library file `libtest.so.1.0.1`, there will be an entry called `SONAME` in dynamic section, that will say this library is called `libtest.so.1`. When you link a program against this library, the linked program will store the `soname` of the library under `NEEDED` entry in the dynamic section.

If you want to verify, what exactly is in which ELF file, you can try to run:

```
readelf -a -W elffile
```

where `elffile` can be either an library of an executable.

If you simply want to get the library version, you can play with:

```
readelf -d  /path/to/library.so |grep SONAME
```

AFAIK, there's no such info (at least not by default) in executable files.

Or you can rely on the program itself or your packaging system, as Rahul Patil wrote.

Comment: nice info, it's new to me never used readelf, if you don't mind , may i ask you where & why use readelf

Comment: Readelf (and similar tools) is useful, when you want to look inside an elf file :). I use it mostly when programming to look up symbols in libraries (when something doesn't work), or when there's some problem with a library. ([man readelf](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_readelf.htm))

Answer (score 19):

You can use `ldconfig -v | grep libraryname` , 
also command has option `command -V` or `binaryfile --version`

example :

```
test@ubuntukrb12:~# ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.13
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

also you can use yum or aptitude based on distro you are using 
eg.

in RHEL5/CENTOS5/Fedora
you can use `yum info packagename` or if it installed then use `rpm --version packagename`

```
 [root@ldap1 ~]# yum info bind97
    Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, security
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirrors.sin3.sg.voxel.net
     * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
     * extras: mirrors.sin3.sg.voxel.net
     * updates: mirrors.sin3.sg.voxel.net
    Installed Packages
    Name       : bind97
    Arch       : i386
    Epoch      : 32
    Version    : 9.7.0
    Release    : 10.P2.el5_8.4
    Size       : 6.3 M
    Repo       : installed
    Summary    : The Berkeley Internet Name Domain (BIND) DNS (Domain Name System) server
    URL        : http://www.isc.org/products/BIND/
    License    : ISC
    Description: BIND (Berkeley Internet Name Domain) is an implementation of the DNS
               : (Domain Name System) protocols. BIND includes a DNS server (named),
               : which resolves host names to IP addresses; a resolver library
               : (routines for applications to use when interfacing with DNS); and
               : tools for verifying that the DNS server is operating properly.
```

In Ubuntu
You can use `aptitude show pkgname` or `dpkg --version pkgname`

```
root@ubuntukrb12:~# aptitude show bind9utils
Package: bind9utils
State: installed
Automatically installed: yes
Version: 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.4
Priority: optional
Section: net
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 306 k
Depends: libbind9-80, libc6 (>= 2.14), libdns81, libisc83, libisccc80, libisccfg82
Conflicts: bind9utils
Replaces: bind9 (<= 1:9.5.0~b2-1), bind9 (<= 1:9.5.0~b2-1)
Description: Utilities for BIND
 This package provides various utilities that are useful for maintaining a working BIND installation.
```

Comment: For `rpm`, I think you'll want `rpm --query pkgname` to list the version string (`rpm --version` will print the version of `rpm` itself; the same might be true for `dpkg`)

Answer (score 10):

Run this to get version information - `strings libssl.so.1.0.0 | grep "1\.0"`

```
SSLv3 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2p-fips  14 Aug 2018
OpenSSL 1.0.2p-fips  14 Aug 2018
TLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2p-fips  14 Aug 2018
DTLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.2p-fips  14 Aug 2018
```

Comment: All the package-system based solutions do not necessarily give definitive version information. This can make a difference when it comes to shared libs installed by custom packages (as in my case) or locally compiled libs. This simple -albeit a bit crude- solution delivers, where even a tool such as `readelf` failed for me. I only feel a bit embarrased I found this post before thinking of this solution myself :-). Thanks!

Comment: this is what I needed, because I needed to check a library that was not installed by the package manager but rather linked by a specific program. This gave me the information I needed.

Comment: This only _happens_ to work because this library has that text as bare strings. It isn't a general solution.

Answer (score 5):

For Redhat based systems do this:

```
ldd [file you want to run] | > needed-packages
```

Check out needed-packages file, make sure there are no path names in the library file names. If so remove them, so "/bin/lib/libx.so.1" change to "libx.so.1"

Find out what package contains the library

```
yum -y provides [lib name]
```

Or put this into a script or run from cmd line:

```
for lib in `cat libs.txt`;
do
   yum -y provides $lib | head -2 | grep " : " >> packages.list
done
```

Next, create the following script or run from cmd line:

```
for package in `cat packages.list | awk '{ print $1 }'`;
do
    yum -y install $package
done
```

You're done, run your program. If you get GUI errors when running. Copy them down and if they are library references, find the packages for those and install the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental answer is that there is no such standard metadata in Linux executable and library binary files. Usually, asking the distribution's package manager is the best you can do — or, as some examples have shown in other answers, hope that the program itself happens to include identifying strings.

With the (upcoming at the time of this writing) Fedora Linux 36 release, we are adding [package information to ELF objects](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Package_information_on_ELF_objects). There is a proof of concept for doing this for Debian as well.

Once this is in place, you can do (for example):

```
$ readelf --notes /lib/libedit.so.0 |grep -A3 .note.package
Displaying notes found in: .note.package
  Owner                Data size    Description
  FDO                  0x00000084   FDO_PACKAGING_METADATA
    Packaging Metadata: {"type":"rpm","name":"libedit","version":"3.1-41.20210910cvs.fc36","architecture":"i386","osCpe":"cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:36"}
```

... and then from there, you can get the package info which will include other information, including the license, project URL, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this

```
pkg-config libgcrypt --modversion
```

This command queries the content `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libgcrypt.pc`, giving you exactly the same result as `pacman -Qi libgcrypt`.

Answer (score 0):

On `rpm`-based systems you can use "`rpm -qf` *library_with_path*" to determine the version and release of the package containing *library_with_path*.

Old UNIX versions had a `what` command (see also [GNU replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/cssc/manual/what.html#index-g_t_0040_0040_0028_0023_0029-125)) that (AFAIR) searches for strings starting with `@(#)` (that was unlikely to occur in binaries at the time the utility was written).

The RCS package also features an utility named `ident` that searches for "RCS keywords" (actually it should search for *expanded* RCS keywords, but it has a rather loose logic, so it finds all other kinds of strings, specifically in shell or Perl scripts).

Linux also seems to keep track which library version introduced which symbol, so you could use the `objdump` command (e.g.) to see that information:

```sh
objdump -T /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 |
awk 'NF == 7 && $2 == "g" { print $6 "\t" $7 }' |
sort -n |
less
```

(Version of `objdump` is from GNU binutils 2.41.0)

For example the output could be:

```text
Base    compute_minrun
Base    __docbDefaultSAXHandler
Base    _fini
Base    get_max_nodeset_len
Base    htmlDecodeEntities
...
LIBXML2_2.9.0   xmlSchemaValidateSetLocator
LIBXML2_2.9.0   xmlTextWriterSetQuoteChar
LIBXML2_2.9.1   LIBXML2_2.9.1
LIBXML2_2.9.1   xmlXPathNodeEval
LIBXML2_2.9.1   xmlXPathSetContextNode
```